# CKEditor Plugin - can allowedContent apply to elements deeper in the hierarcy, or can the MagicLine be disabled on certain elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4, ckeditor, drupal-8

I'm writing a drupal module, based off of the [CKEditor Accordion Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/ckeditor_accordion), but instead using Bootstrap 4. The HTML the plugin inserts looks like this:

```html
<section class="accordion" id="Accordion1">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header" id="heading1">
            <h2><button aria-controls="collapse1" aria-expanded="false" class="btn btn-link"
                    data-target="#collapse1" data-toggle="collapse" type="button">Collapsible Item Heading</button>
            </h2>
        </div>

        <div aria-labelledby="heading1" class="collapse" data-parent="#Accordion1" id="collapse1">
            <div class="card-body">
                <p>Collapsed Text</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

The problem is that the [magicLine](https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/magicline) appears when the user hovers over the child elements of `<div class="card">`).  Is there a way to either disable the magicline only for these elements, or to apply the allowedContent property in a way that also affects the child elements in the hierarchy?  The javascript below shows how I'm using the allowedContent, but it only seems to apply to the outer `<section>` and its immediate child `<div class="card">`.  Any children of the .card div seem to allow any kind of content to be added within.

```js
(function() {
    'use strict';

    // Register plugin.
    CKEDITOR.plugins.add('bscollapse', {
        hidpi: true,
        icons: 'bscollapse',
        init: function(editor) {
 
            ...
            ...

            //elements [attributes]{styles}(classes)
            var allowedContent = 'section[id](!accordion); div(!card)';

            // Command to insert initial structure.
            editor.addCommand('addBSCollapseCmd', {
                allowedContent: allowedContent,
            ...
            ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question:

The magic line plugin can be disabled with the following code - my plugin is called ckeditor_bscollapse.

**ckeditor_bscollapse.libraries.yml**

```
bscollapse_style:
  version: 1.x
  css:
    theme:
      css/ckeditor-bscollapse.css: {}
  js:
    js/ckeditor-bscollapse.js: {}
  dependencies:
    - core/jquery
    - core/jquery.once
    - core/drupal
```

**js/ckeditor-bscollapse.js:**

```
/**
 * @file
 * CKEditor BSCollapse functionality.
 */

(function($, Drupal, drupalSettings) {
    'use strict';

    Drupal.behaviors.ckeditorBSCollapse = {
        attach: function(context, settings) {
            CKEDITOR.config.removePlugins = 'magicline';
        }
    };
})(jQuery, Drupal, drupalSettings);
```

Comment: Hi, How did you go with this module? Would you be kind enough to share you work?